# Restringindo acesso a rotas caso o usuário não estaja não esteja logado Vuejs

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, xampp

não estou conseguindo bloquear as rotas estão passando normal sem a autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e estou com uma duvida de como proibir que acessem as rotas se não estiverem logados, com isso, pensei em algumas soluções que usuariam localStorage,até ai funcionou tudo ok, faço login salvo o token uso o token pra acessar os dados da api.

só estou com dificuldades em travas as rotas do vuejs usando o vue-router fiz ja tentei varias formas e nenhuma impediram de acessar aplicação sem ter feito login.

```
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  if (!to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log(to)
      console.log(store.isLoggedIn)
      next()
      return
    }
    next('/login')

  } else {
    next()
  }

})

> export default [
> 
>   {
>     path: '/',
>     // Relative to /src/views
>     name: 'home',
>     view: 'Dashboard',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }
>     },   {
>     path: '/cliente-index',
>     name: 'Clientes',
>     view: 'Clientes',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }   },   {
>     path: '/sistema-index',
>     name: 'Sistemas',
>     view: 'Sistemas',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }   },   {
>     path: '/sistema-pastas/:id:descricao:path_padrao',
>     name: 'sistema-pastas',
>     view: 'Pastas',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }   },   {
>     path: '/versao-index',
>     name: 'Versões',
>     view: 'Versao',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }   },   {
>     path: '/usuario-index',
>     name: 'Usuarios',
>     view: 'Usuarios',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }   },   {
>     path: '/login',
>     name: '',
>     view: 'Login',   },   {
>     path: '/cliente-sistema/:id',
>     name: 'Cliente Sistema',
>     view: 'ClienteSistema',
>     meta: {
>       requiresAuth: true
>     }
```

Comment: VocÊ precisa utilizar o Router-Guard para saber se o user está logado caso um parametro da rota esteja dentro do rage de "loged", ou seja, coloque um parametro de "loged" em todas as rodas "protegidas" e verifique se a roda acessada é uma rota "protegida" e se for, procurar o "token" e se não existir, fazer push para "login"

Answer (score 0):

use o "guard" do "router" para levar o user de uma rota "protegida" para fora dela caso o "token" não exista.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (findToken(to.meta.requiresAuth)) next()

  next('/login')
})
```

Use a função "findToken" para buscar o token do usuário e caso retorne true ele irá ignorar e continuar porém caso não localize "false" ele enviará o user para o "path" "/login"